# Sodium Carbonate saturation curve

Tags: solubility

Where can I find the saturation curve for Na2CO3 (Sodium Carbonate) versus temperature?
Thanks,
ECD40

Comment: Google, I guess..

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a table in the article on sodium carbonate. You could plot the numbers or Google it. I got a neat curve (attached below)but you have to do a little figuring to get the temperatures. Or you could Google images for sodium carbonate solubility to get other curves.

Washing soda is the decahydrate; soda ash is anhydrous.

Decahydrate:
7 g/100 mL (0 °C)
16.4 g/100 mL (15 °C)
34.07 g/100 mL (27.8 °C)

Heptahydrate:
48.69 g/100 mL (34.8 °C)

Monohydrate:
50.31 g/100 mL (29.9 °C)
48.1 g/100 mL (41.9 °C)
45.62 g/100 mL (60 °C)
43.6 g/100 mL (100 °C)

[image]